# How do I check for an exact string in a line only when it's spaced out from other characters?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file

I would like to check if string "cute" matches part of the string in line. Currently, it does, but it prints it even the line if "cute" is up against other characters.

This is my code:

```
if "cute" in line:
    print(line)
```

But it may print lines such as
"cuteffi" or "cutei934". I have tried checking for "cute" only like this:

```
if "cute" == line:
    print(line)
```

But then this only compares the entire string, even though the string may have contents like
"cute i934", in which case I would want it to print the entire string because "cute" is by itself and spaced out from other characters.

Comment: Did you try splitting the line with space and checking if the individual split elements equal to `cute`?

Comment: Second thefourtheye.  You can even use "if 'cute' in the_line.split()"

Comment: Even if we split the line `cutei934` this concern is remain right?? @SamanthaAtkins

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the lines of the file, [split the line based on whitespace characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and check if any of the split strings equal to the word of interest.

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        split_words = line.split()
        if "cute" in split_words:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Is there a way I can make it case-insensitive easily?

Comment: Convert them to lowercase and verify, use `lower()` method.

Comment: Can anyone solve my doubt ,  `line.split()` will have word `cuteiffi` then above code also works , is it the way you wanted @ally

Comment: @Sanket : If `line.split()`  has `cuteiffi`  if condition will not match since `if "cute" in split_words:` try to find `cute` in the list and will skip if condition since condition doesn't satisfy

Comment: Thank you @SandeepLade, now I got it, where I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest, use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
if 'cute' in line.split():
     # ...
```

Or use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

if re.search(r'(\s|^)cute(\s|$)', line):
    # ...
```

this regex makes sure 'cute' is surrounded by whitespace or the beginning/end of the line. Using word boundaries alone would still match with surrounding punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to regex in this case. By placing string `cute` in between two `\b` makes strict match of `cute`

```
>>> line="i am cutei934"
>>> 
>>> if (re.findall(r'\bcute\b',line)):
    print line


>>> line="i am cute"
>>> if (re.findall(r'\bcute\b',line)):
    print line


i am cute
>>> line="i am 123cute"
>>> if (re.findall(r'\bcute\b',line)):
    print line


>>> line="i am cute right?"
>>> if (re.findall(r'\bcute\b',line)):
    print line


i am cute right?
>>>
```

Comment: @kvk30 : method `find` is not available in `re` module. Instead we can use method `search`

Comment: `re` module does not have `find()` @kvk30

Comment: The regex solution with word boundaries will match lines like `'foo-cute'` however.

Comment: I think it would be better, if we use `find` in `string` method instead of `findall` in `re` . Correct me, if I am wrong. Updated comment please look in to this :)